# Marshall Structure with string array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, serialization, marshalling

I am trying to Marshall a structure that contains integer, strings and string array. I am having problems with serialising the string array. Each time I am getting "FatalExecutionEngine Error". I need to serialise my structure in order to send it over TCP using sockets API.

I found several examples but I don't really understand them :/ Could anyone explain me how does this process works?

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MESSAGE
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 101)]
        public string gameID;
        public int msgID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 101)]
        public string param1;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 101)]
        public string param2;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 101)]
        public string param3;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 101)]
        public string param4;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 101)]
        public string param5;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPTStr, SizeConst = 222)]
        public string[] clientsArray;
    }
```

Comment: why are you trying to marshal to send over TCP? Marshaling is usually used for being to communicate between managed and unmanaged code

Comment: That is a pretty bizarre declaration.  That it doesn't match the native declaration and that the native code therefore corrupts the GC heap is pretty much a given.  Whatever it may look like, little point in forcing anybody to guess at it.

Comment: It is for my university coursework. This is how my tutor told me to declare structure (except the part with array). Also the code given to us is using Marshal class to serialise and deserialise structure (to byte array) in order to send it over TCP or UDP (sockets API). Personally, I have hard time understanding this